# Ionic: How to add a master layout?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am coming from RoR/Laravel framework and working on Ionic very first time. In my app there's a top horizontal menu bar contains links. On clicking link it should load up respective screen. Is there anyway I can create a master layout and then include partials in it based on URL? What's easiest and appropriate way for a noobie?

Comment: If you start the "tabs" e.g: $ ionic start myApp tabs project, it will create for you a very similar structure. With that, you can play around and customize it as you need.

Comment: @jpgrassi But I don't need a tab based app. App has a look similar to a web site; a horizontal bar on top and content changing in the middle.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just pointed you to that, because that template has the same structure you want. Looking at it, you will see how to create your own. I did the same in a project I have worked on.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you the simple "sidemenu" starter template which basically has this what you asked. However, it doesn't have them on top, instead - on a side. But, you will agree that having all the links "on the top" for mobile applications is just "not the way things are designed these days".

Anyways, take a look at [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0RXSDB?p=preview), I think it will resonate with what you're trying to acomplish. The demo is originaly from official ionic example [from Github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu).

So, by clicking the ever so slightly popular "hamburger" icon, you toggle the menu, which (as you will see in the code) is actually a master view that stays on all other views.

Hope this helps nudge you in the right direction.

edit: to satisfy the plunker error (it doesn't let me post the link to plunker without code):

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
  <title></title>
  <link data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```